# Lower confidence interval of a exponentially distributed r.v.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

The life length $T$ of a LED light can be assumed to be exponentially distributed, with probability density function
$$f_{\theta}(t)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{t}{\theta}}1\{t\ge0\},$$

so that $\theta$ is the expectation of $T$. A person buys one LED light, and records the life length for that light to be $t=1000$ hours. Construct a lower $95$% confidence interval for the expected life length of $\theta$.

Please see my (wrong) solution below followed by some questions/queries.

As $T\backsim\mathrm{exp}(\theta)$, then

$$P(T\le t)=F_{\theta}(t)=1-e^{-\frac{t}{\theta}}$$

Let $Z=\frac{T}{\theta}$, then

$$F_{Z}(t)=P(Z\le t)=P(\frac{T}{\theta}\le t)=P(T\le t\theta)=F_{\theta}(t\theta)=1-e^{-\frac{t\theta}{\theta}}=1-e^{-t}.$$

Thus $Z\backsim\mathrm{exp}(1)$. We want a lower confidence interval for the expected life length of $\theta$.

\begin{align*}
1-\alpha &= P(Z\in [\lambda_{\alpha},\infty))\\
&= P(Z\ge \lambda_{\alpha})\\
&= P(\frac{T}{\theta}\ge \lambda_{\alpha})\\
&= P(\theta\le \frac{T}{\lambda_{\alpha}}).\\
\end{align*}

This answer confuses me? Ordinarily I would just plug in $\alpha=0.05$ to get the interval but I assume I have made a mistake for the following reasons

1) My answer would give the confidence interval for $\theta$ in the interval from 0 to infinity. Should not the lower confidence interval be for $\theta$  in the interval from some constant to infinity?

2) I have not made use of the given information "A person buys one LED light, and records the life length for that light to be $t=1000$ hours". Not sure why or how to use this info.

I also have a question regarding my choice of $Z=\frac{T}{\theta}$. I did this because it was done in an example in the textbook and it seems to work in this case. I don't know however why it works? What is the thought process one should go through to "choose" a $Z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are moving in the right direction, but you do need to take the observation
that one LED from the population of interest lasted $X = 1000$ hours.

Here is how to make a 90% two-sided confidence interval (CI) for the exponential mean $\theta$ based on the observation $X = 1000$ from the distribution
$\mathsf{Exp}(\theta),$ with the density function you specify. First,
observe that $X/\theta \sim \mathsf{EXP}(1).$

For suitable $L$ and $U,$ we have
$$P(L < X/\theta < U) = P(1/U < \theta/X < 1/L) = P(X/U < \theta < X/L) = .90.$$
In particular, we choose $L$ and $U$ to be the 5th and 95th percentiles,
respectively, of $\mathsf{EXP}(1).$

Thus, a two-sided 90% CI for $\theta$ is of the form $(X/U, X/L).$
Now, you can make the appropriate modification to get the required one-sided 95% CI.